# Firebase user permission

Tags: firebase

I have two mega parent nodes, but I am currently unable to write to the second one.

```
-users
    uid
        some other info
    uid
-secondParent
    child
        uid
    child
        uid
```

I would like the user to be able to write to his own child of secondParent. Read and write permissions are working correctly for the users parent node, but I can't get it working for the secondParent.

The rule I have currently is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    },
    "parentdNode": {
      "$childID":{
        ".read" : "auth != null",
        "$uid":{
          ".write":  "$uid === auth.uid",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Simulation failure below:
[image: Simulation]

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine what causes your problem. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful), which in this case consists of the minimal code (i.e. the operation that fails), rules and JSON that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write rules for each parents to enable permission

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    },
    "parentdNode": {
      "$childID":{
         "$uid":{
          ".read" : "auth != null",
          ".write":  "$uid === auth.uid",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see above for edit. I don't think your answer quite applies to my situation.

Comment: I tried the edited code, but even in simulator, it fails. I can't seem to be able to create parentNode/$childID.

Comment: I checked above code, it works fine in simulator, can you post any screenshots of those.So that it will be easier for us to pointout

Comment: Added screenshot of simulator. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: i found, In your simulator, location append your uid, /parendNode/someNode/uid/

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, you are trying to write `{"uid":"X","property":"Y"}` to `/parentNode/someNode`. The rules give permission to write `{"property":"Y"}` to `/parentNode/someNode/65ef..aa62`.

JSON trees come with key/value pairs. There is no key `uid` in the scheme you presented, there is a `$uid` which is replaced by the a value from the path you are accessing.

It may still be a bit confusing, but I hope this points to clarifying ideas.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a flat structure where a user creates parentNode, but in reality parentNode belongs to the user, so only that user can write to it, but anyone can read from it. I understand your point. How would I implement what I need to do?

Comment: @Latcie The `secondParent` tree needs a way to know which user created each `parentNode`, so putting inside every `parentNode` a `"uid"` attribute with the user-id of the creator is a good idea (and seems what you intended to do anyway). The rules should check `auth.id` against the value in the `"uid"` field of `parentNode`. Something like: `".write": "!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"`

Comment: Yes, that worked. One more question, if you would. (!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid would mean that if the data exists, the user can write only if the uid is the same as auth.id, correct?

Comment: @Latcie Yes. Perhaps simply having `newData.child('uid').val()==auth.uid` would take care of both cases (as the `newData` will have the `'uid'` child even if the data exists IIRC).